# Specificity over 100

Tags: classification, metric

I am construction a deep neural network for a classification task, when I look at the metrics, I have a specificity of 1.04. Is it possible to have this metric over 100 ? How do you interpret it?
Thank you.

Comment: I think there was an error in my formula, I did Specificity TN/(TP+FP) instead of TN/(TN+FP)

Comment: As you discovered, there was a mistake: it's impossible for specificity to be higher than 1, it's a probability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specificity is defined as

$Specificity = \frac{\sum{True Negative} }{\sum{True Negative}  + \sum{False Positive} }$.

These counts are strictly positive values and as such the **specificity** cannot be negative. You can also see that the specificity must be less than 1 because it is a ratio.

For more details on sensitivity and specificity you can check this answer: [Usage of Precision Recall on an unbalanced dataset](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/17868/usage-of-precision-recall-on-an-unbalanced-dataset/19237#19237)